# TextEditor with Overview of Search Tool's Result?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, search, textmate

I am trying to find a texteditor which can give an overview of Search Tool's Result. I find the current situation of TextMate problematic

[image]

You cannot see the section of one search result without losing your position in the document. The current one-line overview is not enough. 
Therefore, I have to look some other editor, since the search tool is an essential tool in studying.

I am also open for Linux editors because I can compile them for OS X if necessary.

---

Is there any TextEditor with Overview of Search Tool's Result?

Comment: Problem solved. The engineer submitted an improvement in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The engineer responded very fast and submitted a change in the Textmate 2 beta 9. It solves the problem. Now, clicking the find-window, the location of the document is also changed correspondingly.